# .NET Service when finished or just before finishing start another .NET service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've been given 2 .net services. 1 needs to run right after the other. Ideally I'd merge the two services into 1, but given that this is a stopgap measure for only another month or two before its not needed any more I'd prefer not to have to do that much modification and testing on a large change. I was wondering how I could tell service A to start service B after A is basically complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServiceController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)

Represents a Windows service and allows you to connect to a running or stopped service, manipulate it, or get information about it.